# Function Breaks Script for iPhone (Newbie)

Tags: javascript, iphone, function

For some reason the following code breaks my entire Javascript page. (It's for the iPhone).

```
function validate(){
    var ablebuttoncheck = document.getElementById('ablebutton').innerHTML;
    var datebuttoncheck = document.getElementById('datebutton').innerHTML;

    if (ablebuttoncheck =! "Select Date" && datebuttoncheck =! "Select Action"){
        document.save.savebutton.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

If you need the full code see here: http://pastebin.com/R2rQa4s8

On my iPhone I click the buttons and nothing happens. I just want to force the user to press both buttons and select before submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
if (ablebuttoncheck != "Select Date" && datebuttoncheck != "Select Action")
{
        document.save.savebutton.disabled=false;
}
```

Comment: Yep, worked perfect! Knew it was something really simple ha :)

Comment: Also, for some reason if I click either button it enables the submit :X I thought && meant both conditions must be true.

Comment: Yea sorry. :X that's what it's designed for.

Comment: If you buy me an iphone I can help you!

Comment: Ha I would but sadly the economy and, you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

You got it the other way round (I mean the button texts). Try this one:

```
if (ablebuttoncheck != "Select Action" && datebuttoncheck != "Select Date")
{
        document.save.savebutton.disabled=false;
}
```